# Masters thesis if course credits have expired

Tags: graduate-admissions, thesis, masters

I was enrolled in graduate school from 2000-2002 but did not complete my culminating paper before departing for law school.  I always wanted to complete the paper and the degree.  I have now encountered an problem that I suspect would serve as an excellent topic for completion of that degree, if I had encountered it prior to 2010. I was in an urban planning degree program.

Is there any way to revive the courses on my transcript and complete a paper to complete the degree? If so, through which institution if my original institution deems my previous credits expired.

Alternatively, what would be the best means to work with someone to do the research and writing to get the paper into a peer-reviewed journal if I am not enrolled a a university?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Unfortunately there are a few problems with your question: 0) You are asking many questions at once. 1) Your first question depends on your country’s or even university’s regulations. You have to look into those. (See also [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734)). 2) [We do not like to recommend institutions.](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734) 3) Your second question is fine, but probably has been asked before. Please take a look at the [tag:independent-researcher] tag. — Please [edit] your question to address these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you challenge the exam in all of these courses? If not, then you might have to retake the courses. To answer your question about ways to work with someone to do research without being enrolled in a university you can approach the department asking if you could be a research assistant. Its not too common so you might have to try multiple times, but my department has one researcher who has never been enrolled at my university.